# Is there a way to show time in icon tray in GNOME, like Windows?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-shell, clock

Just like Windows, time in right bottom corner of system/icons tray

[image: Windows taskbar clock]

Comment: What do you mean by "just like windows"? Date and time in two different rows? Or just in the bottom corner?

Comment: left bottom corner